Is this a typo in Fulton and Harris?
In the proof of theorem 17.5 the authors write :

… from the discussion in Lecture 15 (see Exercise 15.30): we have contraction maps $$\Psi_{a,b} : \Lambda^ a W \otimes \Lambda ^ b W^ * \to \Lambda^ {a-1} W \otimes \Lambda ^ {b -1}W^ *; $$

Also same expression in the proof of theorem 19.2. which is a similar theorem to 17.2.
But in the exercise 15.30 the expression
is $$\Lambda^ k V \otimes \Lambda ^ l V^ * \to \Lambda^ {k+1} V \otimes \Lambda ^ {l -1}V^ *.$$
To me this looks like a typo in both theorems. Am I missing something?

As far as I'm familiar with contractions, the first expression could be describing contraction and the second one couldn't.

In the copy I'm looking at there is no $V^$ only $V$. They are different maps. One is contracting elements of $W$ against $W^$ while the other is contracting against the identity in $V \otimes V^*$.

Yea, actually I’m confused why the author’s referring to the exercise 15.30

I reckon they intended to refer to exercise 15.19 instead where a similar map is used for symmetric powers.
